# Facebook Custom FBML pages and remote SWF files

Tags: flash, facebook, load, fbml

Is it possible to show Flash content in Custom FMBL tabs for pages?
Can it be done with HTML or must it be FBML if possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have a [fbml tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf/) to embed swf files.

However, Facebook doesn't allow you to show flash content until the user has clicked on your content. If you take a look at the documentation, the tag has a imgsrc parameter. This image will show until the user clicks on it, and then it gets replaced automatically with the SWF movie (and user parameters like uid, token, etc., are passed to the application via REQUEST).